# What if I replace the default MongoDB ID in my documents with my own custom ID, is it going to decrease the response time or retrieval time?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

What if I replace the default MongoDB `objectId` in my documents with my own custom ID which is just numbers, is it going to decrease the response time or retrieval time? Is it possible to add my own Machine ID when `objectId` is being created for a DB document?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You need to set `_id` of the document with your own id. Basically you need to manage that.

Regarding whether it will decrease the response time or not, I don't think it will be too substantial. I would suggest to project the fields inste getting everything. You could pick and choose the fields and that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

as long as the ID is unique and indexed there will be no performance difference